# How to specify limit color for line chart

Tags: javascript, angular, graph, amcharts

How to specify a different color for a line by specifying upper and lower limit in Amchart.

Please find below code for a line chart.

```
 {
          'id': 'g3',
          "title": "Temperature",
          'balloonText':'[[category]]<br><b><span style=\'font-size:14px;\'>[[value]]</span></b>',
          'bullet': 'round',
          'bulletSize': 8,
          "lineColor": "#9524a3",
          'lineThickness': 1,
          'negativeLineColor': '#FF0000',
          'type': 'smoothedLine',
            "negativeBase":8,
            'valueField':"temperature",
        },
```

as I am able to set lower limit using negativeBase property.
How to set the upper limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there isn't a positive base setting you can use a combination of negativeLineColor and lineColor to switch the graph color depending if its decreasing or increasing.

There is an example here:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/155bbc984311730a95242f38c84f78d1

```
"graphs": [{
    "useNegativeColorIfDown": true,
    "lineColor": "#cddd00",
    "negativeLineColor": "#ccb7dc",
```

The graph will be lineColor when increasing and negativeLineColor when decreasing.

https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#useNegativeColorIfDown
https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#negativeLineColor

**OR**

You can take color value from json and use lineColorField.

Please find below json and line graph object

```
{
    "DeviceName": "1Device",
    "Date": "2018-09-11 20:10:55",
    "temperature": 10.00,
    "Color temperature": "#ff3232",
    "humidity": 10.00,
    "Color humidity": "#17c723",
    "co2": 10.00,
    "Color co2": "#ff3232",
    "airpressure": 10.00,
    "Color airpressure": "#9bbd3b"
}

{
    'id': "g"+i,
    "title": data["Parameter"][i],
    'balloonText':'[[category]]<br><b><span style=\'font-size:14px;\'>[[value]]</span></b>',
    'bullet': 'round',
    'bulletSize': 8,
    "lineColor": data["Colors"][i],
  //  "legendColorField": "Color "+data["Parameter"][i],
    "lineColorField": "Color "+data["Parameter"][i],
    'lineThickness': 1,
   //  "negativeBase":5,
    //'negativeLineColor': '#FF0000',
    'type': 'smoothedLine',
    'valueField': data["Parameter"][i],
  }
```